# redefine links for ldconfig

Tags: drivers, video, configuration, symbolic-link

This is my machine configuration:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.4.0-29-generic
Shell: bash 5.0.16
DE: GNOME
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel i7-4700MQ (8) @ 3.400GHz
GPU: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M
Memory: 2248MiB / 15787MiB

I think I have a problem with my libGL.so library and I would like to redefine the link to which is pointing.
In particular when I type `sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i libGL.so` I get:

```
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

and if I type `sudo find /usr -name "libGL.so*"`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

I am thinking that I should be using libGL.so.1.7.0 rather than libGL.so.1.0.
How do I change that in the `ldconfig`?

Comment: Where do you see `libGL.so.1.0`? You will probably find that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1` is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0`

Comment: You're right, so I should probably redefine that symbolic link to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`

Comment: I don't understand why you think that you need to do anything - what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: when I use wine i get this `libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast`

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]